# how can we make a digit after decimal appear like a superscript in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

how can we make a digit after decimal appear like a superscript in java.

here is the example

I have the price say suppose
$14.98, is there a way that i can print those .98 as supercript.

thank you

this is how i am getting price value
<%=price.getBasePrice().setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString()%>

Comment: Where/how are you outputting that value? In the console? In a Swing application? In HTML from a JSP?

Comment: java or javascript? big difference....

Comment: FYI, JavaScript is not a portmanteau of Java and superscript.

Comment: Like a price, or as a superscript?  Superscripts are smaller, but easier.

Comment: OK, that looks like Java + server-side script rather than Javascript. @user968951: in the future, please don't edit the OP's tags w/o getting the OP to clarify.

Comment: @nyshangal: could you please clarify the software environment? Java + JSP? or Java + something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.price').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $val = $this.text(),
        dec_pos = $val.indexOf('.');
    $this.html($val.substring(0, dec_pos) + '<sup>' + $val.substring(dec_pos + 1) + '</sup>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tD9PW/

Comment: :confused: @nyshangal, your question indicates Java, not Javascript. This answer is Javascript, requiring the use of JQuery.

Comment: @Guard: see question. Title / tags got edited by someone other than the OP. The question body was edited by the OP to include Java Server Pages or some other such Java-invocation-via-script (BigDecimal being a Java class). My ":confused:" comment was directed at the OP, who accepted your jQuery answer. The two are not consistent and it would be nice to reconcile the two, either by re-editing the question to remove the Java / Java server pages references, or to unaccept this answer. Either is just fine, but right now there is inconsistency.

Comment: he shows how the data (a number) is included into the page, then asks how to re-format it. I don't see an inconsistence. And at the time I was answering the question the title and tags clearly indicated JS

Comment: @Guard: I repeat: the confusion is not directed towards you. The confusion is directed at the OP who has not clarified his question.

Answer (score 3):

You can superscript in Javascript by using the `.sup()` function:

```
<script>
var j = "14.98";
j = j.split(".");

document.write("$" + j[0] + j[1].sup());
</script>
```

Which Prints:
$14<sup>98</sup>

Comment: Awesome... thanks!  If you'd like to put the decimal back, you could do this... `document.write("$" + j[0] + ('.' + j[1]).sup());`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to output to an HTML page (and I assume you do if you mention Javascript), there is a tag `<sup>` that would do the job:

```
<span>14.<sup>98</sup></span>
```

It's pure HTML, not Javascript, but you can use Javascript to generate this HTML.

Answer (score -1):

You do NOT need to use the decimal point when the cents are superscripted. This is particularly true when the type size is very large on posters or billboards.

Comment: Although this might be helpful in the general sense, it does not address the OP so it should be a comment on the question, not an answer